# Hartman-Grobman theorem on a manifold

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Consider a dynamical system $\Sigma$ on a manifold $M$ of dimension $d$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $d<n$. Let $x\in M$ be an equilibrium point and suppose we wish to determine the stability of $x$. Let $L$ denote the linearization matrix of $\Sigma$ at $x$. Suppose that there are eigenpairs $(\lambda_i,v_i)$ of $L$ with $\lambda_i<0$ such that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for the tangent space $T_xM$ at $x$. Is there a version of the Hartman-Grobman theorem which allows us to conclude that $x$ is asymptotically stable?

In other words, if the linearization is done in the embedding space, can we (for the purpose of stability analysis) consider the linearized system at $x$ to be constrained to the tangent space $T_xM$?

Comment: I do not understand: if the dynamical system is defined on $M$, so how do you define its linearization in the embedding space?

Comment: I restrict the linearization at $x$ to evolve on the tangent space $T_xM$ translated to the origin. Let us assume that the dimension of the manifold is equal to the dimension of its tangent space everywhere. The linearized system has the same number of degrees of freedom as the manifold, which is equal to that of the tangent space. Since the tangent space is a linear space it seems natural to let the linearized system evolve on the tangent space.

Comment: More precise: suppose $dx/dt=f$ is the system with $x\in M\subset R^n$ where $f:M\rightarrow TM$. Then we can take any smooth function $g:R^n\rightarrow R^n$ which is an extension of $f$ and define the linearization in the embedding space as the linearization of $g$ projected on the tangent space of $M$. The projection operator confines the evolution of the linearized system to the tangent space. Now I wonder if there is a  version of the H-G theorem which applies under these circumstances?

Comment: Maybe it can work this way? Grobman-Hartman works in that context because you can take just a chart with your equilibrium point and work with that as with a pretty regular system of ODEs in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Eigenvalues of Jacobi matrix are the same even in different charts (due to how derivatives behave when you go to different chart), so the conclusion is the same.

Comment: What you are describing reminds me of [minimum phase systems in zero dynamics](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4471-5102-9_83-1.pdf). If $M$ is attractive and invariant to the dynamics, then you can look at the restricted dynamics on $M$.